# Align button inline with bootsrap css

Tags: css

Here I have kept two button which should be inline but `login facebook` button get mis aligned. Why?

Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/3ny2u/1/)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <input id="loginButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Login | facebook" onclick="authUserX();" style="display: block;"></input>
        <a href="./redirect.php">
            <input id="loginTwitter" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Login | Twitter "></input>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How about this [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/3ny2u/2/)?

Comment: @RahilWazir:what change did you make?

Comment: Removed the `style="display: block;"` inline css from facebook input button

Comment: good response Rahil. To further add my thoughts, it would be good to place these elements inside the col-md-* as per bootstrap recommendations, they help in laying out various content blocks and it makes it easier to manage as well.

Comment: @ChouOne: `col-md*` is class? can you please give fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chou_one/SAPKD/1/ you basically use rows to place your content and each row can be divided into 12 blocks/grids. it makes it easier to place content like that and bootstrap takes care of the padding/margins etc

Comment: @ChouOne: thanks for the info, can you please tell me what`col-md-12`  does in the fiddle?

Comment: col-md-12 sets it to use the 12 grids and occupy the entire width of the browser window. bootstrap is divided into a 12-grid system. Please see docs here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid its quite easy to get use to it!